# Checked 1st button in 4 slideshows only shows in one

Tags: css

I have 4 parallex slideshows with 4 parent names. I have 5 images in each. 
I want the first button to be checked.
I have set 
 on each slideshow, but only the in the 4th slideshow button-1 is checked.
It's driving me crazy. I've been told it can't be done.

www.pdpdesign.com

Comment: Please expand upon your question. I am unsure of what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

All of your radio name attributes appear to be the same. Give each set a unique name.